# How to align the logo at center in angular material?

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

I am making an angular application with toolbar at top.

Placed a left menu button, logo and a button and a text at last.

**Problem:**

> Here the logo at center is not center to the toolbar but it is
>   center to the first menu button and the other button after logo text.

**Requirement:**

> The logo at the center needs to be center for the **entire toolbar** no
>   matter what is placed next to it.

**Working Stackblitz:**

> **https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-flex-toolbar-21bjwf**

Comment: `margin-left` and `margin-top` you can use.  `margin-left: 43px;` `margin-top:0px`

Comment: That won't work well for all devices I believe..

Comment: it works well in other devices also

Comment: I won't work perfectly, because Logo could be different size (or length).

Comment: based on your logo size you have to set margin. i tried with logo text capitalise and set.

Comment: @aviboy2006, The last right text is a dynamic text and we don't know how much character it  will be so assigning of margin in px for logo doesn't works..

Comment: You can specific margin is % also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make toolbar `position: relative` and position the logo with

```
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

This way, logo will be in the middle, no matter what. Of course, don't forget to stick the actions always to the right (either add `margin-left: auto` to actions or  add `justify-content: space-between` for whole toolbar)

Comment: this will change place of other element.  update in stackblitz and give it here.

Comment: See what happens if I implement your code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-flex-toolbar-hhqtar the right actions sections comes to left and already ```justify-content: space-between``` is for whole toolbar.. You can see the above stackblitz..

Comment: As I said you can achieve this with two approaches. Then use `margin-left: auto` for actions: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-flex-toolbar-h9qt2n